# React - Iterating over State to dynamically generic element

Tags: reactjs

This is a pretty basic question but I've been struggling; Likely due to my 'not quite understanding' how .map() works, and when to make an Object an array etc.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Post from './Post/Post';

class Posts extends Component {

    state= {
        posts: [
                {
                    title: "Test",
                    content: "Some content"
                },
                {
                    title: "Test2",
                    content: "Some Additional Content"
                }

        ]

    };

    render() {
        let post = null;

        post = Object.keys(this.state.posts).map(function (item, key) {
            return <Post title={this.state.posts[item].title} content={this.state.posts[item].content} />
                            })
        return (
            <div>
                <div>List of Posts</div>
                {post}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Posts;
```

This is where I settled, since I got my JSBin version to work. However I'm getting a warning on my 'anonymous callback' function that creates the `<Post>` elements. `<Post>` is just expecting those two props and rendering them. I'm getting a warning on line 26 that mentions state being undefined. Am I not initializing state properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
post = this.state.posts.map(function (item, key) {
            return <Post title={item.title} content={item.content} key={key}/>
       })
```

Your state.posts is an array and you should map over it.

Comment: Just for curiousity: What would be the ES6 version of this?
`...(item, key) => { ... }` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
post = Object.keys(this.state.posts).map((item, key) => {
    return (
        <Post 
            title={this.state.posts[item].title}
            content={this.state.posts[item].content} 
        />
    )
})
```

as Subin says, what you need to do in that case is just map over the posts array.

But, to fix your code is very simple. just use arrow function instead of a regular function.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
post = this.state.posts.map(post => {
  return <Post title={post.title} content={post.content} key={post.title}/>
})
```

When you map over array, you dont need to acces that state again, because post will be assigned to post inside map function. And then just acces `title` and `content`. and dont forget to pass `key`,there i've passed `key={post.title}` but that is not a good solution, because it needs to be unique.

Comment: That makes more sense; I was confusing myself on maps placement, and thought since I was accessing objects within an array I needed to resolve that.